# SQL partitioning on non-enterprise server?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I tried using partition function on my SQL server to partition one of my large table but I got an error saying **"Partition function can only be created in Enterprise edition of SQL Server. Only Enterprise edition of SQL Server supports partitioning."** So I was wondering how does everyone else that doesn't have Enterprise version solve this?

Any advice would be great!

Comment: Actually - a dublicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4557346/sql-server-need-to-partition-data-but-only-have-standard-edition

Comment: Maybe 'upgrade to Enterprise edition'?

Comment: This is shared host...not my server.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Upgrading to Enterprise is not so cheap 8-)

Answer (score 2):

You may develop your own partitioning. The simplest is: several tables and one view to access them. And unified process of modifying the data. There will be some pitfalls like uniquefier of rows in several tables (**distributed PRIMARY KEY**) and many more.

Comment: That was my first tought but I'm not sure how would I prevent double uniquefiers..

Comment: Theoretically using NewId() would give you "globally unique" ids that would be near impossible to have collisions on.  Worse case you can seed your view with an extra identifier "int" column, so even if there is a collision between two views, you have the 2nd id column that's static per view to assist with uniqueness.

Comment: @jklemmack Yep, except that UUID is not very best thing for an index. And better use NEWSEQUENTIALID()

Comment: Thanks guys I have another idea on my mind,since I can order my data on date would it be better performance wise to create tables for each month of the year an create Stored procedure For Selecting,Inserting Updating and Deleting. Since Im usping ASP.NEt I could pass IDs Like 1411012012 And let Stored procedure strip of date and return Row with ID 14 form January 2012 table , same for Insert,update,delete?

Comment: @user1010609 Yup, that is also a decision, but use multiple different stored procedureS o update, delete and select the data. In general - it is the same decision

Comment: @JonathanLeffler uniquefier - is like Unique Identifier over the all the distributed data. Thanks for edit

Comment: Great, I will try to use the idea that I posted and the maybe post results here for future reference. Would It be performance expensive to include in stored procedure to check whether the table exists,so I can let it manage itself ie. create new table if it doesn't exist already?

Answer (score 2):

The method Oleg Dok is referring to is called a "partitioned view".  [Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933141%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) has [covered](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190019.aspx) it [extensively](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345146%28v=sql.90%29.aspx#sql2k5parti_topic4) in the SQL 2000 and 2005 docs.  Just Google the term and you'll get lots of advice.

Basically, if you have N tables with identical schemas, you can create a view on top of them that UNIONs them together and exposes a consolidated view of your data.  There is a [fairly good blog post](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/sql-tools/sql-server-partitioning-without-enterprise-edition/) describing this.  You'll hit some hiccups, especially around performance, so choose indexes wisely, keep the stats  updated, and make sure to query on them properly.

Comment: Wow this is worse than I though it would be.. Anyway thanks for answer! Adter all I am doing it for performance..