# Partitioning in SQL Server Standard Edition with billion of rows

Tags: sql-server, scalability

hi would like to ask about how to partition the following table (see below). The problem i'm having is not in the retrieval of History records which was resolved by the clustered Index. But as you can see the index is based on the HistoryParameterID then TimeStamp, this is needed because the retrieval of rows are based on the columns stated above.

The problem here is that whenever it reaches ~1 billion records, inserts are slowing down since the scenario is there will be 15k rows\second (note this can be 30k - 100k) to be inserted and per row it corresponds to a HistoryParameterID.

Basically, the HistoryParameterID is not unique , it has a one -> many relation ship with the other columns of the table below.

My hunch is that because of the index, it slows down the inserts because inserts are not always at the bottom because it is arranged by HistoryParameterID.

I did some testing using Timestamp as index but to no avail since query performance is unacceptable.

is there any way to partition this by history ParameterID? I was trying it so i created 15k Tables for partition view. But when i created the view it didn't finish executing. Any tips? or is there any way to partition ? Please note that i'm using Standard edition and using enterprise edition is not an option.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[HistorySampleValues]
(
    [HistoryParameterID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [SourceTimeStamp] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
    [ArchiveTimestamp] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF__HistorySa__Archi__2A164134]  DEFAULT (getutcdate()),
    [ValueStatus] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ArchiveStatus] [int] NOT NULL,
    [IntegerValue] [bigint] SPARSE  NULL,
    [DoubleValue] [float] SPARSE  NULL,
    [StringValue] [varchar](100) SPARSE  NULL,
    [EnumNamedSetName] [varchar](100) SPARSE  NULL,
    [EnumNumericValue] [int] SPARSE  NULL,
    [EnumTextualValue] [varchar](256) SPARSE  NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX [Source_HistParameterID_Index] ON [dbo].[HistorySampleValues]
(
    [HistoryParameterID] ASC,
    [SourceTimeStamp] ASC
) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
GO
```

Comment: Isn't that millions of rows?

Comment: billion of rows, that is dstributed to 15k parameter IDs

Answer (score 2):

> I was trying it so i created 15k Tables for partition view. But when
>   i created the view it didn't finish executing. Any tips? or is there
>   any way to partition ? Please note that i'm using Standard edition and
>   using enterprise edition is not an option.

If you go down the partitioned view path (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190019.aspx), I suggest fewer tables (under one hundred).  Without partitioned tables, the optimizer must go through a lot of work since each table of the view could be indexed differently.

I would not expect inserts to slow down with table size if HistoryParameterID is incremental.  However, in the case of a random value, inserts will become progressively slower as the table size grows due to lower buffer cache efficiency.  That problem will exist with a single table, partitioned table, or partitioned view.  See http://www.dbdelta.com/improving-uniqueidentifier-performance/ for an example using a guid but the issue applies to any random key value.

You might try a single table with SourceTimestamp alone as the clustered index key and a non-clustered index on HistoryID nad SourceTimestamp.  That would provide the best insert performance and the non-clustered index (maybe with included columns) might be good enough for your select queries.

Comment: BTW, HistoryParameterID is not incremental so basically it is a random value depending on the scenario 0-15k , 0-30k, and up to 0-100k. Okay will that help? having SourceTimestamp as clustered index and non-clustered index on HistoryId and SOurceTimestamp in insert performance? and at the same time maintain the query performance?

Comment: So will i need to change my query? since currenlty it is  Select .... from Table where HistoryParameterID = paramId AND SourceTimeStamp>= startime and SOurceTimestamp <= endtime,

Comment: The clustered index on SourceTimestamp alone will help insert performance.  As to query performance, an additional key lookup will be needed to retrieve columns other than SourceTimestamp and HistoryID if requested by the query.  That will add more overhead but I can't say if performance will be adequate.  Much depends on how many rows are touched and returned.

Comment: Given the script here Select .... from Table where HistoryParameterID = paramId AND SourceTimeStamp>= startime and SOurceTimestamp <= endtime , Lets say we have a billion records already in the database. and it rows are equaly divided to 15k parameter ids, then initial query of history parameter id will touch a lot of rows or will the non-clustered index help since we added it with the clusterd index of timestamp?

Comment: This is a small fraction of the 1 billion row table size so I would expect a non-clustered index seek and key lookup to return 15K rows.  I expect consistent performance regardless of table size with the worst case being about 15K physical reads for each SELECT.  Much will depend much on performance of the disk subsystem.

Answer (score 0):

Everything you need is here. I'll hope you can figure it out.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188730.aspx

and for Standard Edition alternative solutions exist like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4557380/3903430) answer.

and [this](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/sql-tools/sql-server-partitioning-without-enterprise-edition/) is an interesting article too.

also we implement that in our enterprise automation application with custom indexing around table of users and it worked well.

Here's the cons and pros of custom implementation:

Pros:

- Higher performance that partitioned table because of application's logic awareness.

Cons:

- Implementing routing method and updating indexes.
- Un-Centralized data.

Comment: hi problem is i'm just using SQL SErver standard edition, partitioned tables are available on enterprise

Comment: updated the question to specify that SQL Server standard edition is the only choice

Comment: hi TommyMore, thanks for the feedbak will look into it. I was hoping partition view will do the trick but creating 15k unions since i will be breaking it to 15k tables it failed in creating the view

Comment: is there any way that i can partition the table above so that my index will be on SourceTimeStamp?

Comment: Yes, implement like us implementing distributed Servers or your choice "Table" and seperate the indexing business in your application and then route your application's request based on SourceTimeStamp's custom indexing implementation.

Comment: Partitioned Table is a general feature in SQL Server but if as we implement it based on business logic it'll be super fast.

Comment: hmmm, so 15k-100k tables are okay? then do union for partition view?

Comment: It makes the searching and insertion-update fast. it has nothing to do with viewing data.

Comment: okay, but when i tried creating the partition view it wasn't successful and it was running for minutes and i just canceled it. BTW, i'm creating the partition view so that inserts are easy

Comment: Remember Partitioned Table doesn't make the views faster. It makes your searching faster.